# What is Latin for "relate"?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request, verbs

I mean that sense of *relate* which we find in:

> A relates to B as C does to D.

or when we speak of A and B's *relation*, meaning whatever may be said of A and B without further specification.

If forced to give a definition, I would say that A's relation to B is how A *stands to* B, which is a metaphor (is it?) and couldn't possibly tell someone who didn't already know what a *relation* was.

**Background**

[Referō](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/refero) does not seem to have this sense.

Perseus only seems to give Latin words for other senses:  [relate](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/definitionlookup?type=exact&q=relate&target=la),
 [relation](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/definitionlookup?type=exact&q=relation&target=la).

Comment: For some more options, see _[Smith's Copious and Critical English-Latin Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=jeQIAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA664)_ (section II, starting near bottom of middle column).

Comment: @BenKovitz You could list those options in an answer. Google Books links are not equally accessible to everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about the verb [*contingere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DC%3Aentry+group%3D99%3Aentry%3Dcontingo1)?
One of the meanings (L&S: II.B.2) is "to be connected with or related to, to concern".
I suggest this translation for your example (with slight changes to make cases visible):

> The first thing relates to the second as the third one does to the fourth.
>   *Res prima secundam contingit sicut tertia quartam.*

If you want to say that the first thing relates to the second one in size or some other quality, you can add an *ablativus respectus* to give details: *Res prima magnitudine secundam contingit…*